# Mysql date appear as words in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which contain a date field in a date format (mysql). However, I want the date to appear in words in php. If I want to select those: e.g. 2011-05-15 (mysql), should be displayed as May 15, 2011...

```
$query = "select Date_Hired from registration where IdNum = '".$IdNum."' ";
```

I want that Date_Hired will appear in page in words. thank you.

Comment: MySQL: `DATE_FORMAT`, PHP: date() / strftime(). Google and the manual are ... not your enemies.

Comment: Please edit and include an example of the result set. I suspect you can use `date()` to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select date_format(Date_Hired, '%M %d %Y') from registration
```

[MySQL DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the MySQL `DATE_FORMAT()` function.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Examples:

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2009-10-04 22:23:00', '%W %M %Y');
    -> 'Sunday October 2009'
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2007-10-04 22:23:00', '%H:%i:%s');
    -> '22:23:00'
```